# Cannot save/load checkbox values in sql

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, forms

I have the following code :

```
<input value="1" type="checkbox" data-type="staged" name="data[Detail][<?php echo $key;?>][staged]" id="staged_<?php echo $key+1?>"></td>
```

For the life of me, I cannot get it to save/retrieve data as a checkbox.  If I change the type to say "number" it works perfect.

Is there something simple I am missing?

Answer (score 5):

You are setting the `value` attribute twice.

You had `value="1"` near the end of the checkbox as well as where you were setting it at the start of the checkbox.

```
<input value="<?php echo isset($item['staged']) ? $item['staged']: ''; ?>" type="checkbox" data-type="staged" name="data[Detail][<?php echo $key;?>][staged]"  id="staged_<?php echo $key+1?>">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `checked` attribute of a checkbox in order for it to show the check. As you're reading from a database, you'll need to control this based on the value returned in your data set.

For example, something along these lines should work:

```
<input value="1" type="checkbox" <?php if(isset($item['staged'])) echo "checked=\"checked\""?> data-type="checkbox" name="data[InvoiceDetail][<?php echo $key;?>][staged]" id="staged_<?php echo $key+1?>" class="form-control autocomplete_txt" autocomplete="off">
```

**Edit:** Updated answer based on code posted in chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87816/

Comment: I get the following message when trying to insert that into my php file : syntax error, unexpected '['

Comment: As I said, I'm guessing at your fields, because you posted no information about them. Replace `data[Detail][$key][staged]` with whatever comes back from your DB when the checkbox should be checked.

Comment: Ok, got the thing saving again, but even with the new code, not pulling from the DB the values?

Comment: You'll need to post a more complete code sample for anyone to be able to help you further.

Comment: added my db code pertaining to this, what else would u suggest?

Comment: That's nowhere near enough to be useful. You'll need to post the complete block of code that reads from your DB and outputs your HTML. Preferably your whole php page - but if it's long then please condense it to a relevant example!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87816/discussion-between-steven-and-beercohol).